# Cordova: Issue with absolute position in Android

Tags: android, cordova, css-position

I'm developing a webapp with Cordova. All is fine for the moment except that in one screen, I have a div with this position:

```
position: absolute;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 300px;
bottom: 40px;
```

In my browser (computer or smartphone), the element is correctly positioned but in the built app, the element is something like 10 pixels below.
Here is the meta "viewport":

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, target-densitydpi=device-dpi">
```

Does anyone can help me for that? I really don't know why the pixels are not respected.

Comment: Check the `WebView`, see its position, and its height/width. If you are setting to "wrap_content", then it is possible a redirect is giving you a smaller size than your real content (a quicker response is being outputted without the real size)

Comment: OK, I found the mistake... It was due to "line-height" on elements above. The output height wasn't corresponding to the specified line-height.

For exemple:
- Title: line-height 30px => real output height 26px

Comment: Then please, close this question.

Comment: ok but how? It's not really clear how we can do that...

Comment: click the `delete` if you believe this question is unlikely to help someone else. OR, writte an answer to your question, and accept it (press the `✓` on the left).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Never use "line-height" to specify the "height" of an element. For some reason, in the built app (not in a browser), the output height of the element is not corresponding to the line-height.

I hope this will help someone...